# Filter nested array by matching keywords in both parent or child

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to filter a nested array by matching a keyword. It must return all the objects that matches the name attribute of the parent OR one of its children and filter its children too.

Example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "children": [
      { "name": "abcd" },
      { "name": "efg" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "hjk",
    "children": [
      { "name": "lmn" },
      { "name": "opq" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "children": [
      { "name": "lmn" },
      { "name": "abcdef" }
    ]
  }
]
```

If text input is "ab", then it must return:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "children": [
      { "name": "abcd" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "children": [
      { "name": "abcdef" }
    ]
  }
]
```

(It matches the parent OR at least one of the children, and returns but parent and children)

Right now, I can only filter the parents like this:

```
filteredArray = _.filter(array, (parent) => {
    return _.includes(_.toLower(parent.name), _.toLower(filterText));
});
```

How can I modify this so it filters the children too?

**EDIT:**
A parent can have empty or no children array.

Comment: please explain why `"name": "xyz",
    "children": [
      { "name": "abcdef" }
    ]` is in filtered array?

Comment: Because the child with name "abcdef" marches the input "ab", so it returns both the matching child and the parent. Tha's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: can `children` have nested `children`s?

Comment: No, only the nested structure you can see on the example.

Comment: please take a look at my solution, it uses plain JS and uses regexp as it suits here the best, also it is more readable IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every element check name and filter its children and if one of them is true, push element with filtered children to a new array

```js
const data = [{"name": "abc", "children": [{ "name": "abcd" }, { "name": "efg" }  ] }, {"name": "hjk","children": [{ "name": "lmn"},  { "name": "opq" }  ]}, { "name": "xyz","children": [{ "name": "lmn"
},{"name": "abcdef" } ] }, {"name": "abc"}, {"name": "abc", children: []}];

const res = data.reduce((acc, a) => {
  const ch = a.children && a.children.filter(b => b.name.includes('ab'));
  if(ch && ch.length) acc.push({...a, children: ch});
  else if(a.name.includes('ab')) acc.push({ name: a.name });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This answer looks good, except it should use "includes" and not "startsWith".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention a parent can have empty or no children array.

Comment: One can use array's `push` method safely inside of reduce function

Comment: because you're creating a new array `acc` for `reduce` method call, no need to re-create it again on every step, just mutate existing one and return a reference to it. Easy win for performance

Answer (score 2):

There is no real need in `lodash`. #nodash! Just modern vanilla JS:

```
const regExp = new RegExp(filterText, 'i');

const result = array.reduce((acc, { name, children = [] }) => {
  const next = children.filter(child => child.name.match(regExp));

  if (name.match(regExp) || next.length > 0) {
    acc.push({ name, children: next });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

`name.match(regExp)` will return `null` if substring is not found.

`children = []` handles the case when `parent` has no children.

Also, note that checking for sub-string using RegExp should be much faster than performing multiple transformations and lookups (e.g. `toLower`, `includes`).

Here is the working [repl with your example](https://repl.it/@code4aman/string-lookup-nested-objects-array).

Comment: Is good and the repl is very useful. Can you explain why there is no need in lodash? Over here is kind of mandatory.

Comment: thanks! Why #nodash? The idea of lodash is outdated because of modern JS being pretty rich on standard array/object methods. To support older browsers today we can use `babel` and its `preset-env`. If you want more FP-way - immutability & composition - lodash is also a bad option here. Ramda is much better.

Comment: How once `lodash` pushed out `underscore`, now JavaScript itself must push out `lodash`

Comment: Hi, how to search string for the multiple nested children names.                    
  [{"name": "abc", "children": [{ "name": "abcd","children":[{"name":"abcd"},{"name":"abdc"}] }, { "name": "efg" } ]}];   Could you please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you can use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to do something like this perhaps:

```js
arr = [{"name":"abc","children":[{"name":"abcd"},{"name":"efg"}]},{"name":"hjk","children":[{"name":"lmn"},{"name":"opq"}]},{"name":"xyz","children":[{"name":"lmn"},{"name":"abcdef"}]}, {"name": "xyz"}]

var input = "ab"
filteredArr = arr.reduce((accum, ele) => {
  var obj = {};
  ele['children'] && ele['children'].forEach(e => {
    if (e['name'].includes(ele['name']) || e['name'].includes(input)) {
      obj['name'] = ele['name'];
      obj['children'] ? (obj['children'].push(e)) : (obj['children'] = [], obj['children'].push(e))
    }
  })
  if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0) accum.push(obj);
  return accum;
}, [])

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Comment: @DavidPrieto Don't forget to accept/upvote the answers you find useful :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention a parent can have empty or no children array.

Comment: If search text input is empty, it doesn't return parents without children. If input is empty It should return the exact same array.

Comment: @DavidPrieto I don't fully understand your question.  Current solution works even if `input ` text is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayList = [
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "children": [
      { "name": "abcd" },
      { "name": "efg" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "ab",
    "children": [
      { "name": "lmn" },
      { "name": "opq" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "jdfj",
    "children": [
      { "name": "lmn" },
      { "name": "abcdef" }
    ]
  }
];

function filterArray(arrayList, search){
    return arrayList.filter((item) => {
        let childrens = item.children;
        if(childrens && childrens.length){
          item.children = filterArray(childrens, search);
          if(item.children && item.children.length){
              return true;
          }
        }
        return item.name.indexOf(search) > -1;
    });
}

const filter = filterArray(arrayList, 'ab');

console.log(filter);
```